# Trouble creating calendar in Google API via ColdFusion

Tags: api, coldfusion, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a caledar using the Google API, and it just returns the list of calendars in my account, just like I sent a GET request.  Here is my code:

```
        <cfxml variable="locals.xml">
            <cfoutput>
            <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:gCal="http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005">
                <title type="text">#arguments.argTitle#</title>
                <summary type="text">#arguments.argSummary#</summary>
                <cfif len(arguments.argTimezone)><gCal:timezone value="#arguments.argTimezone#"></gCal:timezone></cfif>
                <gCal:hidden value="false"></gCal:hidden>
                <gCal:accesslevel value="owner" />
                <gCal:color value="#arguments.argColor#"></gCal:color>
                <gd:where rel='' label='' valueString='Oakland'></gd:where>
            </entry>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfxml>

        <cfhttp url="#variables.baseURL#/default/owncalendars/full" method="post" redirect="false" multiparttype="related" charset="utf-8">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin auth=#getAuth(variables.serviceName)#">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/atom+xml">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="GData-Version" value="2">
            <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#trim(locals.xml)#">
        </cfhttp>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ray Camden has some sort of google api - have you checked his blog?

Comment: Yes... I am using his api, which I am expanding to use calendar (his code does docs and analytics).  I wrote a function which gets the calendars in an account successfully.  However, I am following the examples I see on all of the sites I see plus the google api page, and I can't seem to get it to create a calendar, like it is ignoring the header info I am sending.

Comment: I figured it out... I wasn't passing the gSessionId, and the redirection was losing the header info... thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

CFXML creates a ColdFusion XML object. That's an internal CFML construct and is not going to mean anything to the receiving API. I expect that you need to convert it into text.

Try wrapping locals.xml with a ToString(). Like so:

```
<cfhttp url="#variables.baseURL#/default/owncalendars/full" method="post"
    redirect="false" multiparttype="related" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin 
        auth=#getAuth(variables.serviceName)#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type"
        value="application/atom+xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="GData-Version" value="2">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#trim(toString(locals.xml))#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: I made that change, and I still get a 200 and no new calendar is created.

Comment: Ah. Well then. I'm afraid I don't know enough about the Google APIs to offer anything more constructive.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by outputting the XML you're sending into a text-box and displaying it on-screen, to verify that it's in the correct format:

```
<textarea rows="30" cols="120">
  <cfoutput>#trim(toString(locals.xml))#</cfoutput>
</textarea>
```

Another approach you might consider would be to build your XML as a string, not a native ColdFusion XML object that you later convert to a string: (notice that I'm using CFSaveContent instead of CFXML)

```
<cfsavecontent variable="locals.xml">
    <cfoutput>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:gCal="http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005">
        <title type="text">#arguments.argTitle#</title>
        <summary type="text">#arguments.argSummary#</summary>
        <cfif len(arguments.argTimezone)><gCal:timezone value="#arguments.argTimezone#"></gCal:timezone></cfif>
        <gCal:hidden value="false"></gCal:hidden>
        <gCal:accesslevel value="owner" />
        <gCal:color value="#arguments.argColor#"></gCal:color>
        <gd:where rel='' label='' valueString='Oakland'></gd:where>
    </entry>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: I changed it to a cfsavecontent and it still doesn't work.  In fact, I changed it to the example on the Google API page and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you be more specific? "It doesn't work" doesn't help much.